# Java & Google Protocol Buffers: I need an example of how to use Google Protocol Buffers with client-server communication

Tags: java, network-programming, protocol-buffers

Looking for the best example you guys know of.

The examples on the site are with files. But the library should be able to work over a Java.net.ServerSocket, at least I hope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can certainly write protocol buffers to an `OutputStream` and read them from an `InputStream`. The Protocol Buffers project itself hasn't specified an RPC protocol, but [third parties have done so](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/wiki/ThirdPartyAddOns). Alternatively, if you're simply interested in transmitting a message, you should be able to wrap that message in any protocol which allows you to either specify a byte array and retrieve it at the other end, or which gives you a stream-based API.

If you need an example using a specific RPC technique listed in the third party add-ons page, I suggest you look at the home of that particular project.

Comment: Hi, Jon, can you help my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7606051/google-protocol-buffers-in-client-server-when-have-different-packet-type